# why turning off Zend community edition Optimizer+ doesn't have effect on this?

Tags: zend-framework, optimization

When I turn off Optimizer+ in Zend Server CE, we clearly see that number of requests per second decreases (in Zend Controller), but this http://www.php-benchmark-script.com/bench.php doesn't speed up. why?

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the script is so small that the OS is caching the the file and the compilation overhead is so small that it won't make that big of a difference.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @kevin-schroeder says, op-code caches like Zend Optimizer+ come into their own when you are loading lots of files. If you are hitting just one file for your tests this may make such a small difference as to not be measurable. Also I think Zend Optimizer+ does some internal calculations to see if is work while even optimizing ("zend_optimizerplus.enable_slow_optimizations - Enables or disables the optimization passes that may take significant time, based on an internal runtime calculation").

In its default setup Zend Optimizer+ will still have to check the disk to see if the file has changed since the last time it was requested. So that should be taken in to account.

I would say the main reason you won't be able to measure the difference is that benchmark script takes 11 seconds to run. This will mask the small gains made by Zend Optimizer+ very hard to measure. Most of the gains made by op-code caches are around the loading and parsing of the PHP script and not in the running of the PHP code.

I would suggest running the same test but just have it echo out a simple string. Maybe you will be able to measure the difference.